# How can i store server errors in backend?

Tags: backend

I am working on a django project deployed in a ec2 in a tmux session. whenever an api throws error or give internal server error, it's just difficult to find it in tmux everytime.

I wanted to know if there is anything for storing these errors somewhere, something like crashlytics that will store api the errors and at the end of the day i can analyse them and fix them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are working inside AWS the most transparent connection would be to send them to [cloudwatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/), you can do so by installing [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html) and [watchtower](https://pypi.org/project/watchtower/)

```
pip install watchtower boto3
```

An then defining [Django logging settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/logging/#configuring-logging). Here you want to pay attention to 2 sections, the formatter which indicates how your log messages will be formatted. The handler which is who is going to manage the log stream and how to connect to it, in this example AWS through a Boto3 session.

```
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "formatters": {
        "aws": {
            "format": "%(asctime)s [%(levelname)-8s] %(message)s [%(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]",
            "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
        },
    },
    "handlers": {
        "watchtower": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "class": "watchtower.CloudWatchLogHandler",
            "boto3_session": logger_boto3_session,
            "log_group": "DemoLogs",
            "formatter": "aws",
        },
        "console": {"class": "logging.StreamHandler", "formatter": "aws",},
    },
    "loggers": {
        "watchtower": {"level": "INFO", "handlers": ["watchtower"], "propogate": False,}
    },
}
```

There is a great tutorial by Jordan Haines here:

https://dev.to/jordanahaines/django-and-cloudwatch-logging-in-a-place-you-can-see-3bc7

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is [AWS CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html). I don't actually know anything about AWS really though.

Maybe [this artcile](https://dev.to/jordanahaines/django-and-cloudwatch-logging-in-a-place-you-can-see-3bc7) will help. Or [this one](https://zoejoyuliao.medium.com/plug-your-django-application-logging-directly-into-aws-cloudwatch-d2ec67898c0b).

I guess otherwise you could use [Sentry](https://sentry.io/welcome/) or something similar if you don't want to couple to AWS.